# is there any workaround for broken v8 date parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, v8

V8 Date parser is broken:

```
> new Date('asd qw 101')
Sat Jan 01 101 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

I can use fragile regular expression like this:

```
\d{1,2} (jan|feb|mar|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec) \d{1,4}
```

but it is too fragile. I cannot rely on `new Date` [(issue in V8)](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4202) and also moment cant help me because moment is [getting rid off date detection (github issue-thread)](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

is there any workaround for broken v8 date parser?

*To be clear. We have Gecko and V8, both have `Date`. V8 has broken Date, Gecko has working one. I need the `Date` from in Gecko (Firefox).*

[image]

<del>Update: It’s definitely broken parser https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2602</del>
[nope, `Status: WorkingAsIntended`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2602#c2)

Comment: What dates do you want to detect?

Comment: @Bergi added expected dates

Comment: If that's the date you want to detect, I do not see what is wrong with your regex solution.

Comment: Because it’s too fragile and target only narrow subset of Dates.

Comment: probably I need to change original question

Comment: So what subset of Dates do you want? Either you accept what `Date` accepts, or you explicitly define your own formats (possibly with the help of momentjs or similar libs)

Comment: I want to detect eny valid date, which detection is perfectly done in all engines except V8. e.g. try to run `new Date('asd qw 101')` in your firefox

Comment: I think what @Bergi is asking is, what is _your_ definition of a valid date?
I'm new to node, but what is your expected result of parsing `new Date('asd qw 101')`?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov: then you probably have to look in the Gecko sources and extract their parsing algorithm if that's the behaviour you want to replicate.

Comment: Yep, do you have a link for Firefox sources? cannot find them on GItHub

Comment: not only on github, anywhere

Comment: 3200 lines of code =((( https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/jsdate.cpp

Comment: @VladimirStarkov: C'mon, it's not [that bad](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/jsdate.cpp#L719-1162) :-) But yeah, you should ask yourself whether you really need exactly that.

Comment: can you simply filter out parsed dates older than 1900? i doubt you need to use the year 0003 very often...

Comment: I can, but it doesn’t solve the problem, because look: `new Date('asd qw 2015')`

Comment: At any given moment in time you should know the exact format of your incoming data, so in any given moment in time it's possible and trivial to validate your data. If you pass any rubbish to your code - you get the rubbish as its outcome. GIGO.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Date` objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC and have the following constructors

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date),

> **dateString** in `new Date(dateString)` is a string value representing a date. The string should be in a
> format *recognized* by the **Date.parse()** method (***IETF-compliant RFC 2822
> timestamps*** and also a version of ***ISO8601***).

Now looking at the [v8 sourcecode](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js?r=18400) in date.js:

```
function DateConstructor(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms) {
  if (!%_IsConstructCall()) {
    // ECMA 262 - 15.9.2
    return (new $Date()).toString();
  }

  // ECMA 262 - 15.9.3
  var argc = %_ArgumentsLength();
  var value;
  if (argc == 0) {
    value = %DateCurrentTime();
    SET_UTC_DATE_VALUE(this, value);
  } else if (argc == 1) {
    if (IS_NUMBER(year)) {
      value = year;
    } else if (IS_STRING(year)) {
      // Probe the Date cache. If we already have a time value for the
      // given time, we re-use that instead of parsing the string again.
      var cache = Date_cache;
      if (cache.string === year) {
        value = cache.time;
      } else {
        value = DateParse(year);               <- DOES NOT RETURN NaN
        if (!NUMBER_IS_NAN(value)) {
          cache.time = value;
          cache.string = year;
        }
      }

    }
...
```

it looks like `DateParse()` does not return a NaN for for a string like `'asd qw 101'` and hence the error. You can cross-check the same with `Date.parse('asd qw 101')` in both *Chrome(v8)* [which returns `-58979943000000`] and *Gecko (Firefox)* [which returns a NaN]. `Sat Jan 01 101 00:00:00` comes when you seed `new Date()` with a timestamp of -58979943000000(in both browsers)

> is there any workaround for broken v8 date parser?

I wouldnt say V8 date parser is broken. It just tries to satisfy a string against [RFC 2822 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) in the best possible way but so does gecko and both <strike>break</strike> *gives different results* in certain cases.

**Try** `new Date('Sun Ma 10 2015')` **in both Chrome(V8) and Firefox(Gecko) for another such anomaly.**
Here chrome cannot decide weather 'Ma' stands for 'March' or 'May' and gives an *Invalid Date* while Firefox doesnt.

**Workaround:**

You can create your own wrapper around `Date()` to filter those strings that V8's own parser cannot. However, subclassing built-ins in ECMA-5 is not feasible. In ECMA-6, it will be possible to subclass built-in constructors (Array, Date, and Error) - [reference](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#subclassing_built-in_constructors)

However you can use a more robust regular expression to validate strings against *RFC 2822/ISO 8601*

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\. |\s)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.|\s)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.|\s)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.|\s)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

[image: Image-regex]
Image generated from [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com)

So, seems like v8 aint broken, it just works differently.

Hope it helps!

Comment: it helps a lot. btw, today I found an issue from March 2013 that V8 parser should return `NaN` btw I still think its broken https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2602, so probably it is officially broken

Comment: or probably not "Status: WorkingAsIntended"

Comment: Exactly! IMHO, It depends on the how _well_ a parser supports the standards(RFC/ISO). They mostly cover the scenarios where they should work as expected, but throw junk in certain use-cases. As an example, V8 does throw a TypeError(as expected) on `new Date('asd qw 21')` but qualifies a similarly structured string `new Date('asd qw 121')` as a date(which it shouldn't). One can always come up with a better regex/parsing technique for wider support, but still cannot guarantee it to work for every valid format and junk string. Exhaustive testing in such cases is neither practical nor possible :)

Comment: That regex and diagram are pretty - but I can't seem to get it to work with RFC2822, and it certainly doesn't accommodate ISO8601.

Answer (score 11):

You seem to be asking for a way to parse a string that might be in any particular format and determine what data is represented.   There are many reasons why this is a bad idea in general.

You say moment.js is "getting rid of date detection", but actually it never had this feature in the first place.  People just made the assumption that it could do that, and in some cases it worked, and in many cases it didn't.

Here's an example that illustrates the problem.

```
 var s = "01.02.03";
```

Is that a date?  Maybe.  Maybe not.  It could be a section heading in a document.  Even if we said it was a date, what date is it?  It could be interpreted as any of the following:

- January 2nd, 2003
- January 2nd, 0003
- February 1st, 2003
- February 1st, 0003
- February 3rd, 2001
- February 3rd, 0001

The only way to disambiguate would be with knowledge of the current culture date settings.  Javascript's `Date` object does just that - which means you will get a different value depending on the settings of the machine where the code is running.  However, moment.js is about stability across all environments.  Cultural settings are explicit, via moment's own locale functionality.  Relying on the browser's culture settings leads to errors in interpretation.

The best thing to do is to be explicit about the format you are working with.  Don't allow random garbage input.  Expect your input in a particular format, and use a regex to validate that format ahead of time, rather then just trying to construct a `Date` and seeing if it's valid after the fact.

If you *can't* do that, you'll have to find additional context to help decide.  For example, if you are scraping some random bits of the web from a back-end process and you want to extract a date from the text, you'd have to have some knowledge about the language and locale of each particular web page.  You could guess, but you'd likely be wrong a fair amount of the time.

**See also: [Garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)**

Comment: Thanks for reponse, basically I dont need to rely on momentjs at all. I can use Date and will pretty happy with it. The point is that Firefox implementation is working and Chrome’s one is broken.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov I wouldn't say chrome is broken, it's just trying to parse the input string

Comment: @maioman probably it’s not broken, but it doing its job not good enough

Comment: @VladimirStarkov without knowing the subsets it's like crawling in the dark; but if you divided the string and fed it to the Date object instance with `setFullYear` , `setMonth` , `setDate` you should have a more consistent result , take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/cztaL0bu/)

Answer (score 10):

> [ES5 15.9.4.2 Date.parse:](https://es5.github.io/x15.9.html#x15.9.4.2)  /.../ If the String does not conform to
>   that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific
>   heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. Unrecognizable
>   Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format
>   String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.

So that's all right and according to the citation above result of v8 date parser:

1. `new Date('asd qw 101')` : Sat Jan 01 101 00:00:00 GMT+0100
   (CET)
2. `new Date('asd qw')` : Invalid Date

Comment: sorry, I didn’t get why it is `Sat jan 01 101` instead of `NaN NaN 101`

Comment: @VladimirStarkov because `NaN` is not a valid part of a date.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov: because dates don't consist of parts, they're just timestamps. And `asd qw 101` was parsed into the one representing second zero of year 101.

Comment: @royhowie this part promises that parse will return NaN "Unrecognizable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN."

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Becaus `any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats`

Comment: @Bergi \@royhowie probably, im not smart enough, but can you describe it in more details?

Comment: btw, why any non-v8-based browsers have different behavior?

Comment: @Bergi it should be `NaN` and V8 has apropriarate issue https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2602

Comment: @stdob-- you seems to be right with heuristics this "any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats"