# Invalid string is converted to date

Tags: javascript, datetime

Hi I have a string 'Windows-10' which when I try to parse via new Date() constructor it is getting parsed and gives a completely valid date as 'Mon Oct 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'

I dont know why is this happening I also tried it with other Windows string such as 'Windows-7', 'Windows-99' etc. and they all parse easily.

Comment: Doesn’t happen in Firefox 65.0a1. I get `Invalid Date`.

Comment: What is your computer date?

Comment: Is this just because you're interested, or does it cause trouble?

Comment: Which browser or environment are you using?

Comment: @Xufox Works in Chrome 70

Comment: Node 11.0.0 outputs `2001-09-30T22:00:00.000Z`, `2001-06-30T22:00:00.000Z`, `1998-12-31T23:00:00.000Z`, respectively. Apparently, `99` is parsed as the year 1999, `10` and `7` as the months October and July, respectively.

Comment: `new Date('whatever-27')` results in Invalid Date but `'whatever-37'` and `'whatever-127'` are parsed

Comment: [`new Date(dateString)` uses `Date.parse(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax). Docs say that ["results may be unexpected"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Parameters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any workaround for broken v8 date parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964943/is-there-any-workaround-for-broken-v8-date-parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you witnessed is implementation-specific, which for the one-arg `Date(value)` constructor is covered by the [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse) spec in chapter [20.3.2.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value). Your example will walk through to step 3.b.ii.1. which states that the string will be parsed according to the rules laid out in chapter [20.3.3.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse) for the `Date.parse(string)` method. That method specification defines:

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format ([20.3.1.16](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. Unrecognizable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause **`Date.parse`** to return **NaN**.

Because your strings obviously do not comply with the Date Time String Format the browser falls back to its implementation-specific algorithm. My Chrome 70, e.g., returns a `Date` object for the current time which corresponds to calling the no-args `Date()` constructor. IE11 on the other hand parses the string to `NaN` and returns a Date object with an *"invalid date"* value.